# Android Facebook events using Graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created the event successfully using Graph Api as follows.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Sample Emvent");
params.putString("start_time", "2013-07-04");
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/events", params, "POST",
                             new EventListener(), null);
```

I got some id as response. Now my questions are
 1) How can I  share this event ?.
 2) How can I Check-in into this event?

Any help greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can share the event with this url:
  `https://www.facebook.com/events/EVENT_ID`
- You can RSVP the user as *attending* using the Graph API, by issuing an HTTP POST to EVENT_ID/attending. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: Hi Gil Birman I didn't understood how to share event with the url you have given. By opening that url ,getting html content as response. When I opened that url in browser it is showing event page only,but the event is not shared.If you don't mind  Can you explain about that event share in detail?

Comment: Any one can help in Sharing of Events?

Comment: replace EVENT_ID with your event's id and then post the link on your wall.